# How to improve: Given two integers, return the number of digits that they share

Tags: java, algorithm, int, hashtable

I received this question during an interview, the question is

> Given two integers, return the number of digits that they share.

For example 129 and 431 would return 1 - as they both share the digit `1`, but no other digit. 95 and 780 would return 0, since none of the integers overlap.

My thoughts are just iterate through the digits, store them into a hashtable and check `.containsKey.`

**My Java solution:**

```
public int commonDigits(int x, int y) {
     int count = 0;
     HashTable<Integer, String> ht = new HashTable<Integer, String>();

     while (x != 0) { 
         ht.put(x % 10, "x");
         x /= 10;
     }

     while (y != 0) {
         if ((ht.containsKey(y % 10)) {
             count++;
         }
         y /= 10;
     }

    return count;
}
```

But this takes up O(n) space and O(n + m) time, anyways I can improve this?

Comment: You might find this belongs on [CodeReivew](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: What's the point of ``(ht.get(y % 10) != "y")``? It's not going to work (because of String comparison) and there's never a ``y`` in the map anyways.

Comment: yeah you are right, ill take that part out

Comment: number of unique digits, or any digits? answer for "111" and "11" is 2 or 1?

Comment: You don't need a `HashTable`, a set should be sufficient (and since you're dealing with digits an array might be yet better). Anyhow you'll have to iterate over the digits of the 2 numbers and store those of one so O(n) memory and O(n+m) runtime is probably the best you can get.

Comment: 111 and 11 would return 2, so nonunique digits

Comment: Even `int[10]' would be sufficient ...

Comment: @Fildor Thomas does note this already, I removed a similar comment.

Comment: @AndyTurner oops I have to admin I didn't read his comment when typing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is codereview.stackexchange.com for "review working code" requests.

Comment: "O(n) space and O(n + m)": what is n, what is m ???

Comment: Since there seem to be quite some misconceptions on what you're actually after, can you update your question with some additional examples, e.g. 111/11 (= 2?), 11/111 (=2? or =3?), 12341234/422 ( =3?), etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just use some simple bit fiddling?

```
public int commonDigits(int x, int y) {
  int dX = 0;
  while (x != 0) {
    dX |= 1 << (x % 10);
    x /= 10;
  }
  int count = 0;
  while (y != 0) {
    int mask = 1 << (y % 10);
    if ((dX & mask) != 0) {
      count ++;
      dX &= ~mask;
    }
    y /= 10;
  }
  return count;
}
```

This just sets a corresponding bit in dX for each digit in x. In the second loop, for each digit in x, the code checks whether it has an entry in dX. If so, it's counted and the bit is reset to avoid double-counting (note that this is missing in your code, consider 123 and 141).  Obviously doesn't use any additional storage (dX and count could just be bytes if that matters).

Note that you don't need a HashTable in your solution -- you could just use a HasSet or a BitSet..

Your code translated to using a BitSet with the double-counting problem fixed:

```
public int commonDigits(int x, int y) {
  int count = 0;
  BitSet ht = new BitSet();

  while (x != 0) { 
     ht.set(x % 10, true);
     x /= 10;
  }
  while (y != 0) {
     if ((ht.get(y % 10)) {
         count++;
         ht.set(y % 10, false);
     }
     y /= 10;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Both snippets work exactly the same way, the latter just has some more overhead for the BitSet (and embedded array) instance.

This article shows why a BitSet is better than a boolean array in the general case: http://chrononsystems.com/blog/hidden-evils-of-javas-byte-array-byte

**Edit**:

If counting the same digit multiple times is actually desired (was not clear from the examples in the question), use an int array to store the counts:

```
public int commonDigits(int x, int y) {
  int count = 0;
  int[] digits = new int[10];

  while (x != 0) { 
     digits[x % 10]++;
     x /= 10;
  }
  while (y != 0) {
     if (digits[x % 10] > 0) {
         count++;
         digits[x % 10]--;
     }
     y /= 10;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: I call hacks. _Bit_ hacks.

Comment: Brilliant way to go !

Comment: As far as I understood, double-counting is desired - 112 and 131 shall return 2. 112 and 133 shall return 1.

Comment: @Fildor It wasn't clear to me from the question whether this is the case (given the examples provided initially), have extended the answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't agree with your intepretation. 112 and 131 share the digit 1, i.e. they share 1 digit.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes. But OP stated in comments that if they share the same digit twice, it shall be counted as 2. So 112 and 131 share digit 1 two times.

Answer (score 6):

This is your solution with the minimum storage (an array of 10 bytes instead of a hash table):

```
public int commonDigits(int x, int y) {
 int count = 0;
 byte[] digits=new byte[10];

 while (x != 0) { 
     digits[x%10] ++;
     x /= 10;
 }

 while (y != 0) {
     if (digits[y % 10] > 0) {
         count++;
         digits[y % 10] --;
     }
     y /= 10;
 }

return count;
}
```

The solution is optimum in running time `O(n+m)`, where `n` is the number of digits in `x` and `m` is the number of digits in `y`. You cannot do less than enumerating the digits of `x` then the digits of `y`.

Comment: a) Stefan postet a very similar solution. b) Booleans won't be enough because doubles shall be counted.

Comment: a) I didn't see his solution. Sorry. b) I modified the answer

Comment: After edit: Now it's good :)

Comment: `digits` can be a `byte[]`,saving the storage.

Comment: @DannyChen Yeah true, but the storage is still O(10). I changed the answer anyway. Thanks.

Comment: changing to `byte` saves storage but decreases the maximum number of countable occurrences in a number significantly. OP did not name a bound for that but it would have to be taken into account for production code.

Comment: @Fildor The type `byte` counts up to 127. So, we are good till the day we see an `int` number in Java having a digit occurring more than 127 times ;-)

Comment: Oh, haha. Nevermind. I was thinking wrong. Dough!

Answer (score 4):

Since there are only 10 possible digits, why not just store an integer array? Indexed from 0-9, one for each digit. Loop through each digit and increment the corresponding array element. The space complexity of this depends on what you define to be "constant" - this will always take up 10 units of space (would be 10 bytes in C/C++, not sure how JVM does it)

By *conservation of information*, you *have* to loop through each digit of both numbers (they are independent so you can't just infer one from the other), so your time complexity will remain at O(m + n). Also I think by O(n) you really mean O(log n), as this is the number of digits in any *representation* of the number.

Comment: non-unique digits :P see the comment section, so instead of boolean array store into 'int' array

Comment: I'd guess that with `O(n + m)` he means `n` and `m` to be the number of digits and not the numbers themselves.

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah because 111 and 11 should return that they share 2 digits while with a boolean array you'd only get 1 (as you'd get for 111 and 1 etc.).

Comment: @Thomas it would be more correct to say O(log n) because the number of digits depends on the representation of the number (i.e. which base), whereas the number's value is a universal concept. But minor issue.

Comment: @Thomas You can use the boolean array to store wether the digit exists, but for counting you only need *one* int, not a whole int[].

Comment: @Thomas apologies! missed that

Comment: @Polygnome no can't just use _one_ int since if I'm not mistaken 11 and 111 should also report 2 shared digits which you can't do with just knowing whether the digit exists or not.

Comment: "plus malloc metadata block" -- btw don't actually use `malloc` for a fixed-size array of 10 bytes!

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah: no, unless otherwise specified, in algorithm analysis the variables (`n` and `m` in this case) by convention are the size in bytes of the input data to the algorithm. Since linear factors disappear anyway in the complexity analysis, we overlook whether the input is base 2, base 10, binary-coded decimal, or whatever else. That said, it *was* odd of the questioner to write the code with fixed-size input, two `int`s, and then talk about complexity in terms of the input size ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop true, true, yes. And oops :D wth was I thinking

Answer (score 2):

There is at maximum 10 digits that can be shared. This means you don't need a complicated data structure like Hashtable, an array or bitmask will suffice!

You would simply iterate over the first number, and every digit you hit is marked as "true" (in your bitmask or array). You can even short-circuit this and return early if you have found every digit once (which is easy and cheap with a bitmask). Then go over the second number. Every time you hit a digit that is also marked as true, increase the counter. If the bitmask contains every digit, short-circuit by returning the length of the number (its highest exponent), otherwise return the counter at the end.

This doesn't reduce O-complexity, but it reduces memory footprint and adds some short-circuits for large numbers.

For example, if the first number is 1234567890, then it will always share as many digits with the second number as the second number has decimal places.

Comment: That doesn't fit the OP's requirement of non-unique digits. As per comment the OP want to return 2 when comparing 111 and 11, i.e. both numbers share 2 digits. With boolean values you'd only be able to return 1. If you'd check how many of the digits in the second number would be present in the first then try 11 and 111. If I'm not mistaken the OP still wants to return 2 but here you'd either be able to return 1 (there is one unique shared digit) or 3 (all 3 digits of 111 are present in 11) - that doesn't seem to meet the requirements.

Comment: Thats not true. For the input 111 and 11 my suggested solution would return 2, just as the OP suggested. Please read carefully what I use the bitmask for and what I count. This isn't symmetric, and 11 and 111 would return 3, but Ops spec isn't reallyclear about that, and Ops demo code doesn't do that, either.

Comment: Please read my comment carefully, as I already mentioned that you'd be able to return 2 for 111 and 11 but not in the case 11/111 - I'm fully aware of what you are doing but as I said, I _assume_ (from the question as well as the comments) that he's basically after an intersection of some sort of cardinality map (i.e. sum of lowest digit cardinalities for each input number).

Comment: Err, his requirements are *very* shady. I've just used the same logic he used in his code example since hat seems to do what he wants. You can blow the whole thing up arbitrarily complex (to me, the question as posed would also include position of the digit, but thats a different thing again).

Answer (score 2):

A hash table is overkill, just use an array of ten flags (whether you pack them in a single integer with bitwise operations or keep independent variables is up to you).

Scan the first integer and raise the relevant flag for every digit.

Scan the second integer and reset the relevant  flag for every digit.

Return the number of true resets (from 1 to 0).

**Update**: to deal with duplicates, the flags need to be replaced by counters.

---

If both numbers have M digits, they must all be looked at so that the time complexity is at certainly Ω(M).

The case of the space complexity is less clear. All solutions presented here are O(N), where N is the number of possible digits (10 in the decimal base). But O(1) space is possible: take every digit of the first number in turn, check if it is the first such digit in the first number (to avoid counting duplicates), then check if it exists in the second number. This is an O(M²)-time process, but O(1)-space only.

**Update**: to deal with duplicates, every time you process a digit, count the number of identical predecessors in the first number; when looking for a match in the second number, also match the number of predecessors.

So one may wonder if a O(M)-time, O(1)-space solution is possible.

---

My solution is O(M+N)-time, O(N)-space. The +N in the time complexity is only required for the initialization of all N flags. If you accept not to count the initialization, you can write the algorithm in such a way that it clears all the flags it has set (so that the algorithm can be played again) and this yields a O(M)-time, O(N)-space solution.

---

There is an easy O(M Log M)-time, O(M)-space solution, by sorting the two strings of digits and counting the identical digits in a merge-like step. Can be of use if M is very small compared to N.

Comment: "111 and 11 would return 2, so nonunique digits" - OP's comment to the question.

Comment: @Fildor: this was added after my answer, so I would be tempted to just ignore it. I don't think that this impacts my comments very much. In particular, the O(M²)-time, O(1)-space solution can be adapted to deal with duplicates and the question about existence of O(M)/O(1) remains.

Comment: Granted, I just wanted to make you aware in case you wanted to address that.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution doesn't account for duplicates.

```
# 11, 211 -> 2
```

You're right to use a hash, it's faster than an array. Gonna do this in python because it's faster to type...

```
# Returns an array containing the shared digits
def getShared(num1, num2):
    shared = []
    digits1 = getDigits(num1)
    digits2 = getDigits(num2)
    for digit in digits1:
        if digit in digits2:
            while digits2[digit] > 1 and digits1[digit] > 1:
                digits2[digit] = digits2[digit] - 1
                digits1[digit] = digits1[digit] - 1
                shared += [digit]
            del digits2[digit]
            del digits1[digit]
    return shared

# Given an integer, returns a dictionary with the keys as the digits,
# and the value as the number of times the digit appears
def getDigits(num)
    dict = {}
    while num > 0:
        newDigit = num % 10
        if newDigit not in dict:
            dict[newDigit] = 1
        else:
            dict[newDigit] = dict[newDigit] + 1
    return dict
```

Comment: it doesn't have to account for duplicates, he wants them to be counted

Comment: So 11 and 211 should return 1, not 2?

Comment: This is faster to type????? A hash is faster than an array???

Comment: Faster to type a hash in Python than Java.. And yes. In both cases you need O(n+m) to go through the digits. But this adds only O(n) to check for duplicates, as opposed to something bigger if you're checking for matches between two arrays. In terms of O complexity it's kind of the same, but the hash is definitely faster.

Comment: See my answer and tell me if anything can be faster. The array is indexed by the digit. This is kind of hash.

Comment: "You're right to use a hash, it's faster than an array": nonsense.

Comment: Ya Ahmad, yours is way better. What I meant about the hash was the lookup instead of comparing digits directly. You guys were all ahead of me.

Comment: @Yaelle No problem. We all learn everyday.